# Heroku cli - how to run a python function by command line?

Tags: python, heroku, command-line, heroku-cli

I have a Python project hosted on Heroku, and I am trying to run by command line (Heroku cli) a specific function inside my script. Is it possible? I have not found anything about this in Heroku documentation.

Example:

myfile.py

```
def hello_world():
 print("hi")
```

Command 1  (This works OK, but run all file):

```
$ heroku run python myfile.py
```

Command 2 (This is not working)

```
$ heroku run python myfile.py hello_world
```

Comment: You can use https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec to get a shell in the dyno, but it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is unrelated to heroku, you are just running a normal `python` interpreter via `heroku run`.

Comment: Thanks dude, you are right, I was mistaken. I just used as a terminal cmd and it worked